# SQL Server - Count Midnight Occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a patient with an admit date and a discharge date. How can I count how many times midnight occurs within the time range?

So using the below table, Patient 1 would be admitted on 1/31 24:00:00, 2/1 24:00:00, and 2/2 24:00:00. Any ideas how to return these three occurrences?

```
create table temp
(   PatientID varchar(12),
    AdmitDate datetime,
    DischargeDate datetime
)

insert into temp values ('Patient1','1/30/2020 13:23:44', '2/2/2020 15:12:52')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *exactly* what `datediff()` does:

```
datediff(day, admitdate, dischargedate)
```

Comment: datediff is just going to give me the difference between two dates. I'm asking for the count of a specific time in a date range. Where datediff() doesn't work well is if admit is 11:59pm and discharge is 12:01am.. datediff() will give me 1, but midnight occurred 2.

Comment: @dcrowley01 . . . You are asking for midnight and that is what `datediff()` does.  If you want to count a different time, then ask a *new* question and be explicit.  This answers the question you have asked here.  I don't see how your example would return "2", because midnight only occurs once if those times are on adjacent days.

Comment: @dcrowley01 Wait, what? You're saying if the patient was in the hospital for two minutes then midnight happened twice? If you want to count how many days were affected (and not how many midnights occurred, which is what you asked), then you can always add 1 to datediff *except* maybe the case where one or both boundaries is exactly at midnight (but you'll need to be a lot more explicit defining all of your edge cases).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Let me provide more clarity here. If you're admitted on 1/1/2020 11:59 pm and discharged on 1/3/2020 12:01am, then datediff() will give me a 1, right? However, midnight actually occurred twice.

Comment: Datediff will give you 2.  It's really not so difficult to test that for yourself , right?

Comment: 100%... I don't know why I thought it different, but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While a simple `datediff` calculation works on most occasions, there are a few edge cases. In this [example from NHSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLLXL.png), you must count an extra day. For context, check out the [PDF](https://www.cdc.gov/nhsn/pdfs/patientday_sumdata_guide.pdf). So if a patient was admitted at midnight, and that was the elected time for the organization to count patient days, then that patient must be counted. Of course, PatientY has only been in for a minute, not a full day. But overall, in the long run, I suppose it averages out.

```
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp 
   (PatientID VARCHAR(12),
    AdmitDate DATETIME,
    DischargeDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES 
    ('Patient1', '1/30/2020 13:23:44', '2/2/2020 15:12:52'),
    ('Patient2', '1/1/2020 23:59', '1/3/2020 00:01'),
    ('PatientX', '1/1/2020 08:00', '1/5/2020 17:00'),
    ('PatientY', '1/1/2020 00:00', '1/5/2020 00:01') -- 5 days according to NHSN

SELECT 
    PatientID,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) MidnightCount,
    CASE 
        WHEN AdmitDate = CAST(AdmitDate AS DATE)
            THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) + 1
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, AdmitDate, DischargeDate)
        END MidnightCountNHSN
FROM #Temp
```